# How to correct change position of a Object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a code to generate a 2D array into GameObjects, my currently properties are:

```
Width: 1920
Height: 1080
Camera Size: 540
2D Array size: 30x16
Each block represents 64x64 pixels
```

My problem is that I position my blocks from -960 to 960 (1920 width) and -540 to 540. But when I do that, the block that was supposed to be at the first position gets wrongly put on:
[image]

So from the vision of the camera, probably most people would figure out that I have to put half of the block width added to its x position, and half of blocks height decreased from its y position, but when I try that, this occour:
[image]

Code:

```
float height = Camera.main.orthographicSize *2f;
    float width = height / (float)Screen.height * (float)Screen.width;
    Destroy(map);
    map = new GameObject();
    print("W: "+width+". H: "+height);
    lastH=height;
    lastW=width;
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<16; j++) {
            if(mapa[i,j]>0){
                GameObject aux = objetos[mapa[i,j]-1];
                float wX=aux.transform.localScale.x,hY=aux.transform.localScale.y;
                print ("wX: "+wX+", hY: "+hY);
                float unidadeW = 2*(float)lastW/(float)(20*wX);
                float unidadeH = 2*(float)lastH/(float)(20*hY);
                //aux.transform.localScale = new Vector3(unidadeW,unidadeH,0);
                GameObject t = (GameObject)Instantiate(aux, new Vector2(j*wX*0.64f-width/2,-i*hY*0.64f+height/2),Quaternion.identity);
                t.transform.parent = map.transform;
            }
        }
    }
```

OBS: There are several stuff that I don't use anymore because i'm changing the code, so don't mid it.

And I ask, WHYYYY?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to make a distance between two units is their diagonal, see the image below:
[image]

Doesn't matter which is your orientation point, if its top left or center, the distance between the blocks will be √2*side, so the correct distance between mine was around 22, and I can find it by doing this equation:

sqrt(2)/2*32=22.62 (the correct distance between two tiles of 64x64), instead of using 64+ at the last x and 64+ at the last y the right way to do is by adding 22.62 at both multiplications.